elasticsearch 7.12 version and 7.17 version difference
I found that in version 7.12, all the data can be searched without adding size when searching.
However, in version 7.17, if you do not add size to the search, only the default 10 pieces of data will be returned at a time.
This issue seems to have occurred after the version was upgraded to 7.17.
But I can't find the corresponding content in the official description.
So I asked everyone to see if anyone had experienced a similar situation.
Help me check this problem.
in version 7.17. use this code to search
GET /pd_goods/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

only the default 10 pieces of data will be returned at a time
and then adding size
GET /pd_goods/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1000
}

there will be return 1000 pieces of data

Can you reproduce it right now or do you base this statement on your memory of how 7.12 used to work? As far as I know, this behavior didn't change since v0.4. It was always 10 records by default.

When using v7.12, the size was not added when searching, but the users of our system did not report that the search data was too small. After upgrading to v7.17, some users reported that the search data was incomplete. Based on this I guess there are some problems between the two versions. Maybe I can roll back the version to v7.12 and verify again if this was the case with v7.2.

I am sure that with the sample query that you posted in your question you will get exactly the same results in 7.12 and 7.17. I think you need to dig deeper into user reports and uncover the actual problem that the user is seeing and identify the actual query that is getting sent to elasticsearch. Once we can separate elasticsearch issue we can start looking at the query and result to see what is causing the issue.
